# How to get lost passphrase?

Tags: json-rpc, php, passphrase

I set up the bitcoin daemon and galaxycash daemon on my server. And i was using this library

> easybitcoin.php

to contact the daemon via rpc . Somehow i remeber that i used this function `encryptwallet("test")`
but whenever i try to use this function now `sendfrom("walletaddress","towalletaddress",1);`

i get this message

> Error: Please enter the wallet passphrase with walletpassphrase first.

so i used this function `walletpassphrase("test",60);`

but am getting this error

> Error: The wallet passphrase entered was incorrect.

Does any wallet address has it's own passphrase in bitcoin daemon?
Or it's only 1 passphrase for all wallets in 1 daemon?
And how can i get the passphrase of the address because i need to use it with this function `sendfrom`
Am using rpc for PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that an individual address is not a wallet. A wallet is a collection of addresses.

> Does any wallet address has it's own passphrase in bitcoin daemon? Or it's only 1 passphrase for all wallets in 1 daemon?

A wallet has its own passphrase; passphrases are not per-address (that would be impractical).

You can have multiple wallets in a daemon each with different passphrases (the most recent versions of Bitcoin Core support multiwallet).

> And how can i get the passphrase of the address

Passphrases are not automatically generated. You as the user must have set it. If you do not know the passphrase, then there is nothing that you can do.

Comment: Okay so there's a big diffrent between wallet and address . I generate new address using the function 'getnewaddress' . but this does not allow you in the parameters to generate your passphrase .
How can i generate it? and how to create new wallet instead of address?

Comment: Passphrases are not automatically generated. You have to set it yourself on the entire wallet using the `encryptwallet` or `changewalletpassphrase` commands. You cannot create a new wallet from the command line; you have to start Bitcoin Core with the `-wallet` option in order to specify a new wallet that will be created if it does not exist.

Comment: So does it mean in when you start a bitcoind . you only have one wallet? . you can only create one wallet?
Or is it possible that i can create another one?

Comment: Means all the rpc command are happening in one wallet . you cannot run two wallets in same time in daemon?

Comment: You can run two wallets if your software supports multiwallet (which the latest version of Bitcoin Core does). By default, you will only be using one wallet.

Comment: Yes as i checked am having the last version.
One more last question.
As am trying to create a board of trade where everyone can sign up and have a bitcoin address.
Which best way is to use only one wallet and give everyone an address from that wallet . or to use multi wallet and give the addresses from different wallet.
And what's the exactly different between using 1 wallet or multi? the benefit?

Comment: If you have further questions, please use the Ask Question button. Your question is off topic for this answer that we are commenting on.